# High accuracy (training and testing) Pytorch CNN model predicted wrong label even with training dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I trained a CNN model using Pytorch with high accuracy (~99%) and low loss (~0.002) in both the training set and the validation set. However, my model predicted the wrong image’s label even with images in the training dataset.

[image]

I used black and white images (1 channel) for my dataset. My dataset is balanced and has 6 labels. Each image’s size is 240px width and 180px height.

I tried to predict images in my training dataset using my trained model (~99% accuracy). I tried to predict in every folder (label) and got these results:

Images in the first label got high accuracy (~99%)
Images in the 5 other labels got very low accuracy (0-20%)
This is my code:

Data prepared code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import random
import pickle

DATADIR = "../Data/"

# All categories you want your neural network to detect
CATEGORIES = ["Back", "Down", "Forward", "Left", "Right", "Up"]

# Checking all images in the data folder
for category in CATEGORIES:
    path_image = DATADIR + category
    # print(path_image)
    for img in os.listdir(path_image):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_image, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        # print(img_array.shape)

training_data = []


def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path_image = DATADIR + category
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path_image):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_image, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (240, 180))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass


create_training_data()
random.shuffle(training_data)
random.shuffle(training_data)
random.shuffle(training_data)

X = []  # features
y = []  # labels

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

plt.imshow(X[0], cmap="gray")
plt.show()
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 240, 180, 1)

print(X.shape)
print(y[0])

pickle_out = open("Saved_Model/New_Model/X.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("Saved_Model/New_Model/y.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

CNN model code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch import flatten
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from torchsummary import summary

X = pickle.load(open("Saved_Model/New_Model/X.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("Saved_Model/New_Model/y.pickle", "rb"))



# normalizing data (a pixel goes from 0 to 255)
X = torch.tensor(X / 255.0, dtype=torch.float32, device='cpu')
y = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.long, device='cpu')

# Define the CNN model
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        # initialize first set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32,
                               kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        # initialize second set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64,
                            kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128,
                               kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=1)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        # self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        # initialize first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers 42240
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=84480, out_features=128)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64)
        self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        # initialize our softmax classifier
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=6)
        self.logSoftmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        # pass the input through our first set of CONV => RELU =>
        # POOL layers
        # print(x.shape)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        # pass the output from the previous layer through the second
        # set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
        # print(x.shape)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.maxpool2(x)
        # print(x.shape)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.maxpool3(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 84480)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu5(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        output = self.logSoftmax(x)
        return output

model = CNN().cuda()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

# Train the model
num_epochs = 10
batch_size = 32
train_size = int(X.shape[0] * 0.85)
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X[:train_size], y[:train_size])
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X[train_size:], y[train_size:])
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

train_acc_list, val_acc_list = [], []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_loss, train_acc = 0, 0
    model.train()
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs.permute(0, 3, 2, 1))
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
        train_acc += (outputs.argmax(dim=1) == labels).sum().item()
    train_loss /= len(train_loader.dataset)
    train_acc /= len(train_loader.dataset)
    train_acc_list.append(train_acc)

    val_loss = 0
    val_acc = 0
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in val_loader:
            inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()
            outputs = model(inputs.permute(0, 3, 2, 1))
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            val_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            val_acc += (outputs.argmax(dim=1) == labels).sum().item()

    val_loss /= len(val_loader.dataset)
    val_acc /= len(val_loader.dataset)
    val_acc_list.append(val_acc)

    print(f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Training Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Training Accuracy: {train_acc:.4f}, "
          f"Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Validation Accuracy: {val_acc:.4f}")

# Save model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'Saved_Model/New_Model/CNN_Model.pth')

# Print final training and validation accuracy
final_train_acc = train_acc_list[-1]
final_val_acc = val_acc_list[-1]
print(f"Final Training Accuracy: {final_train_acc:.4f}")
print(f"Final Validation Accuracy: {final_val_acc:.4f}")


# Plotting the accuracy changes during the training phase
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(train_acc_list, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(val_acc_list, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

summary(model, input_size=(1, 180, 240))
```

Code to predict every folder (label):

```
import os
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
from PIL import Image

# Set the path to the folder containing your images
folder_path = '../Data/Down'

CATEGORIES = ["Back", "Down", "Forward", "Left", "Right", "Up"]

# Load the trained model
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        # initialize first set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32,
                               kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        # initialize second set of CONV => RELU => POOL layers
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64,
                            kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128,
                               kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=1)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        # self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        # initialize first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers 42240
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=84480, out_features=128)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64)
        self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()
        # initialize our softmax classifier
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=6)
        self.logSoftmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.maxpool2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.maxpool3(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 84480)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu5(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        output = self.logSoftmax(x)
        return output

model = CNN()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("Saved_Model/New_Model/CNN_Model.pth"))
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = model.to(device)
model.eval()

# Define image transformations
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor()
    # transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5), std=(0.5))
])

# Open the output file in write mode
output_file = open('..\Code\Prediction_Accuracy\Down.txt', 'w')

total_file = 0
accuracy_file = 0

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    img_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
    img = Image.open(img_path).convert('1')
    img_tensor = transform(img).unsqueeze(0).to(device)

    total_file += 1

    # Predict the image class
    with torch.no_grad():
        predictions = model(img_tensor)

    predicted_class = predictions.argmax().item()
    if predicted_class == 1:
        accuracy_file += 1

    output_file.write(f"Image: {filename}, Prediction: {predicted_class}\n")

print(f"accuracy: {accuracy_file/total_file}")
output_file.write(f"accuracy: {accuracy_file/total_file}")

output_file.close()
```

Comment: *Images in the first label got high accuracy (~99%) Images in the 5 other labels got very low accuracy (0-20%)* -- this usually indicates the training dataset was not properly balanced (unlike you mentioned).